# Retrieve Files from Subfolder

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

In [Microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=dedicated#location--folder_or_filepath)  it is stated:

> If you specify LOCATION to be a folder, a PolyBase query that selects
> from the external table will retrieve files from the folder and all of
> its subfolders. Just like Hadoop, PolyBase doesn't return hidden
> folders. It also doesn't return files for which the file name begins
> with an underline (_) or a period (.).

I tried that on my own, so I created a data lake whereby `folder 2` and `folder 3` contain also csv files, the super-folder is `folder 1`:

[image]

When Running the query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE secureFiles
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'https://datalakeXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/files/'
);
GO


CREATE  EXTERNAL TABLE  mytab(
    id INT,
    p_name VARCHAR(20),
    age INT
)
WITH(
    DATA_SOURCE=secureFiles,
    LOCATION= 'folder1/',
    FILE_FORMAT=CsvFormat
)
GO

select * from mytab;
```

I only get the content of the file `m1` and `m4` - so the data from the subfolders seems not to be gathered. Is the docu from Microsoft outdated?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve files data from sub folders create External data source of ADLS Gen 2 with credentials

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  DATA SOURCE [adls] WITh   
(

   TYPE = HADOOP,
   LOCATION = 'abfss://<container name>@<storageAccName>.dfs.core.windows.net', 
   credential = cred

)
```

Create external file format

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  FILE FORMAT [csvFormat] WITH
(
   FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT
)
```

[image]

Create external table with below code:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  TABLE product(
    Id NVARCHAR,
    Name varchar(20)
)
WITH
(
     LOCATION='folder1/dbo.product.csv',
     DATA_SOURCE=[adls],
     FILE_FORMAT=[csvFormat] 
)
```

The data is from sub folder so need to mention

```
LOCATION='<folderName>/<fileName>',
```

[image]

**Updated:**

Retrieve files data from sub folders create External data source of ADLS Gen 2 with credentials

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  DATA SOURCE [adls1] WITh   
(

   TYPE = HADOOP,
   LOCATION = 'abfss://<container name>@<storageAccName>.dfs.core.windows.net', 
   credential = cred

)
```

Create external file format

```
 CREATE  EXTERNAL  FILE FORMAT [csvFormat1]
 WITH (
       FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
       FORMAT_OPTIONS (
           FIELD_TERMINATOR = N',',
           USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = False
      )
)
GO
```

Create external table with below code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[products13]
( 
    [Id] [varchar](20)  NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](20)  NULL
)
WITH (
      DATA_SOURCE = [adls1], 
      LOCATION = N'folder1/', 
      FILE_FORMAT = [csvFormat1]
 )
GO
```

The data is from sub folder so need to mention

```
LOCATION = N'folder1/'
```

[image]

Comment: my question was if files from non-hidden subfolders are included in the query result (such as the spec suggests)

Comment: Give Location = "<FolderName>/**" in external table script

Comment: Yes, but read the Microsoft Documentation: here something different is stated

Comment: Please check the above update.